# full email id passing in url

Tags: php, forms, email

i am new to php .i am trying to develop a application with html and php.
 i passed variable from form to url.all code given below

```
<FORM METHOD="get" ACTION="action1.php">
Type your first name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="FirstName"> <br/>
Type your last name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="LastName"> <br/>
Type your email:<INPUT TYPE="email" NAME="email">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Click and See">
</FORM>
```

the output url is http://example.com/action1.php?FirstName=jon&LastName=Kuri&email=xyz%40abc.com

but i want it to be http://example.com/action1.php?FirstName=jon&LastName=Kuri&email=xyz@abc.com

How to do it.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

update:
      `<?php 
      $email="xyz@gmail.com";
      $decode=urldecode($email);
      ?>`

```
  <FORM METHOD="get" ACTION="action1.php">
  Type your first name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="FirstName"> <br/>
  Type your last name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="LastName"> <br/>
  Type your email:<INPUT type="hidden" NAME="email" value="<?php $decode; ?>">
  <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Click and See">
  </FORM>
```

This also does not give me the required result.here i am pre defining email value.

Comment: You can't....btw, why dont you use post instead of get?

Comment: The url encoding is there for a reason: to pass special characters, that might not be passed directly by text. Or to encode characters with "special meaning", for instance an "/" or "&". You should look at url decoding instead.

Comment: Please note: It's bad practice to pass sensitive/private information around in a URL.

Answer (score 3):

Urls are encoded, that's why `@` becomes `%40`, it comes from the way data is sent from the form/ If you use `get method`, this is how it will be formated in the url.
But don't worry, what you get in php is correct and decoded.

Answer (score 2):

You are simply seeing certain characters encoded to be URL safe (like `@`).

When you examine the data server-side it will look like the original data on the form. You don't have to decode anything, PHP does it for you automatically.

From [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php):

> The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already decoded.

Try to `echo $_GET['email']` in PHP and you'll see `xyz@abc.com` again.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect as you are decoding an already decoded email.

```php
<?php 
    $email="xyz@gmail.com";
    $decode=urldecode($email);
    // @ should be encoded as %40
?>
```

should be:

```php
<?php 
    $email="xyz%40gmail.com";
    $decode=urldecode($email);
    // returns "xyz@gmail.com"
?>
```

As stated in other answers, php will in most cases take care of this for you, however if you're trying to test your code with strings the above is necessary. Alternatively you could encode your email string too:

```php
<?php 
    $email="xyz@gmail.com"; // no encoding here
    $decode=urldecode(urlencode($email));
    // returns "xyz@gmail.com"
?>
```